# Magento2 SQL Query Resource Model

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

1. I am Create a extension vendor attribute extension . I need to get all the vendor attributes in a grid format. My resource model is like this.

   ```
   $entityTypeId = $this->entityModel->setType(
       \My\Marketplace\Model\Vendor::ENTITY
       )->getTypeId();

      //echo 'entityId'.$entityTypeId;
     parent::_initSelect();
     //Join eav attribute table
     $this->getSelect()->joinLeft(
     ['eav_attribute' => $this->getTable('eav_attribute')],
     'eav_attribute.attribute_id = main_table.attribute_id'
     );
       $this->getSelect()->where('eav_attribute.entity_type_id=?',$entityTypeId)->order('main_table.attribute_code','DESC');
   ```

When i run this query getting below error message.both tables having attribute_code field here.

```
Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'attribute_code' in order clause is ambiguous, query was: SELECT `main_table`., `eav_attribute`. FROM `my_marketplace_vendor_form_attribute` AS `main_table`
LEFT JOIN `eav_attribute` ON eav_attribute.attribute_id = main_table.attribute_id WHERE (eav_attribute.entity_type_id=9) ORDER BY `main_table`.`attribute_code` ASC, attribute_code ASC
```

2. I have another issue as well. When i try to save data to database it is giving error like this

   ```
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
            $data[]= array(
            'attribute_id' => $model->getId(),
            'attribute_code' => $attributeCode,
             'is_visible' => $is_visible,
             'sort_order' => 0,
             'store_id' => 0,
             'use_in_registration' => $use_in_registration,
             'position_in_registration' => 0,
             'use_in_left_profile' => 0,
             'fontawesome_class_for_left_profile' => 0,
             'position_in_left_profile' => 0
             );
             $objectManager->get('My\Marketplace\Model\Vendor \Form')->insertMultiple($data);
   ```

It is giving following error message.But data is inserting finely in database.

```
Notice: Array to string conversion in /var/www/html/b2b/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php on line 228
```

Comment: try to change `order('main_table.attribute_code', 'DESC');` to `order('eav_attribute.attribute_code', 'DESC');`

Comment: I tried it , giving same error. when i print the total query it is like this.  SELECT `main_table`.* , `eav_attribute`. * FROM `ced_csmarketplace_vendor_form_attribute` AS `main_table`
LEFT JOIN `eav_attribute` ON eav_attribute.attribute_id = main_table.attribute_id WHERE (eav_attribute.entity_type_id=9) ORDER BY `eav_attribute`.`attribute_code` ASC